# Is there a way to convert array into json file and save/post it in S3 bucket(aws)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am new to aws.
I am trying to make a web app which would let user insert texts in the text fields(assume two text fields) and then the inserted texts get converted into Json file and gets save to the S3 bucket.I am using javascript and Angularjs . Can anyone help me with the procedure to do so?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please clarify your question -- are you looking for assisting with the part that copies a file to Amazon S3, or are you seeking help on the JSON part? Feel free to update your Question to show the code you've tried so far and any errors/problems you're experiencing. That way, you'll be more likely to receive Answers to your Question.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly basic flow to create. It does require some tweaking as you'll need to create a trigger for the code to execute like a button click or what have you, but it should be close enough to what you're looking for.

The process would concise of the following:

**THE HTML**
The elements here will be accessed by your JavaScript / AngularJS code.

```
<input type="text" id="your_id_1" value="example1" />
<input type="text" id="your_id_2" value="example2" />
```

**THE JAVASCRIPT**
This code will extract the values from your inputs and create a JSON object to transfer.

```
// This script tag will download the AWS SDK and make it available to your code
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aws-sdk/2.6.15/aws-sdk.min.js"></script>

// This script tag will contain your own code
<script>
  // Get the values from the inputs into variables
  var input_1_value = document.getElementById("your_id_1").value; //example1
  var input_2_value = document.getElementById("your_id_2").value; //example2

  // Create the JSON object
  var json_object = {
    "input_1_value" : input_1_value,
    "input_2_value" : input_2_value
  };

  // Create an instance of the S3 client
  var s3 = new AWS.S3();
  AWS.config.update({ accessKeyId: "your_access_key", secretAccessKey: "your_secret_key" });
  AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';

  // Provide the necessary details for the file upload (The bucket to upload it to and the file name you want it to have.)
  var params = {
    Bucket: 'your_bucket_name', /* required */
    Key: 'your_file_name' /* required */
  };

  // Perform the upload, which will print either outcome (result or error) in the console.
  s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else     console.log(data);           // successful response
  });
</script>
```

**THE BUCKET POLICY**
The above code won't work until you apply a CORS policy to the bucket you're uploading to, allowing your JavaScript code to interact with it. 
I'm not going to explain CORS at length, you'll find plenty of documentation of it on google. The reason WHY we have to use this, is explained [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/cors.html).

To apply the bucket policy:

1. Log in to the AWS console
2. Navigate to S3
3. Click your bucket
4. On the right-hand side, click properties
5. Go to permissions and select CORS policy.
6. Paste the following code into the box

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
      <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>https://example.org</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
        <ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>
        <ExposeHeader>x-amz-meta-custom-header</ExposeHeader>
      </CORSRule>
    </CORSConfiguration>
```